# Organization Name does not match Organization ID when privately distributing an app

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I am receiving the error above when trying to save the changes under 'Pricing and Availability' for a particular app on the App Store Connect web application. I have verified that this is the right data for the organization as it was taken from their Apple Business Manager enrollment information.

Is there another error or something I may not have done before trying to save these changes that I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution for me - I was using Chrome, tried everything (I was pulling apart network requests and everything).

Switching to Safari solved the issue.